# Clear Chat - Clears all of the messages in the chat window.

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Ever wish you could simply clear all of the messages from the chat window (similar to a terminal)? Well now you can with this UserScript! Simply install it using the link below and click the clear button - and that's it!

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

Get it here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/clear_chat.user.js

#### Platform

Runs on any browser that supports UserScripts.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript and uses jQuery.